# How to pass the json response in ResponseBody of WireMock

Tags: wiremock

I am trying to validate the json response. Have gone through the documentation in wiremock and also tried github example as below syntax.

https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/blob/master/src/test/java/ignored/Examples.java#374

```
@Test
public void toDoListScenario() {
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/todo/items")).inScenario("To do list")
            .whenScenarioStateIs(STARTED)
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withBody("<items>" +
                            "   <item>Buy milk</item>" +
                            "</items>"))); }
```

How to enter the json response in Body Section.

```
 {
 employeeDetails : [
   employeeName : ABCDE,
   employeeID : 12345 ]
 }
```

Is the below representation is correct. Please help me on this.

```
.withBody("employeeDetails:" +
          "employeeID" : "12345" +
          "employeeName" : "Preethi" + )
```

Comment: This answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76455655/wiremock-how-to-include-request-json-body-into-the-response-body/76470633#76470633 with Junit 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just format the text as json:

```
.withBody("{\"employeeDetails\":[" +
      "\"employeeID\" : \"12345\"" +
      "\"employeeName\" : \"Preethi\"]}")
```

and set the header to

```
.withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/json"))
```

Comment: what does "equalTo" come from in equalTo("application/json"))?